# Store movies/tv shows from iTunes on external drive

Tags: itunes

I'd like to store only movies and tv shows on my external drive. I don't mind keeping my music on my built-in drive. Is there a way to set iTunes so that it only looks for the videos rather than all media?

Answer (score 1):

Use TuneSpan. Here's [an article I wrote about it](http://www.techhive.com/article/1167721/move_itunes_media_files_to_other_locations_with_tunespan.html).